# Calculating PostgreSql DB size in python

Tags: postgresql

I want to write a cron job to calculate PosgreSql database size in python. Is there any API's in python. Cron job will find all the databases & calculate sizes for all of them daily.

Answer (score 7):

Just a query:

```
SELECT
    pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(current_database())) AS dbsize;
```

Fetch the result and you're done.

And for all databases in a cluster:

```
SELECT
    pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname))
FROM 
    pg_database;
```